# WebAPI2 consume form angular2 error Not Found

Tags: web-services, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I wont to consume Web Api2 async in Angular2 project, but i have some errors, when i try a request to the method.

My method is:

```
 private baseUrl2 ='http://localhost:50348/api/Users/GetUsers'
    getuser(): Observable<IUser[]>
    {

        console.log(this.baseUrl2);
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl2)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .do(data => console.log('getuser: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

My [HttpGet] method at WebApi is :

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users.ToList();
    }
```

I have configure Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors also and at Startup.cs i put AllowSpecificOrigin policy:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:50348/"));
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            // Shows UseCors with named policy.
            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

        }
```

But when i run my angular project a call method form angular project i have an error as:

> Object { _body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not
>   Found", headers: Object, type: null, url:
>   "http://localhost:50348/api/Users/Ge…" }

When i try to call web api method from browser , not form angular project ,it works

```
[{"Country":"test","Id":1,"Name":"test","OtherInfo":"test","Surname":"test"}]
```

Whats wrong? Could you help  me?

Comment: Try to change the code [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users.ToList();
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Get()
    {
        return _context.Employee.ToList();
    }
```